# react external javascript in component during server-side render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, external

I want to use external Javascript "fabric.js" in my component during server-side render.

Any tips how do it? I still get an error message "fabric is not defined".

Normally, I include Javascript into HTML `<head>`, but during server-side render it doesn't work. Thank you so much.

Comment: You would need to import external scripts in order to use them as far as I know. Although fabric.js operates on the canvas, which won't exist server side. What are your intentions of using fabric?

Answer (score 0):

If using Webpack you could try using the following: [webpack-isomorphic-tools](https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools)

This should allow you to require assets on the server. However with something like fabric.js, which uses canvas you probably won't be able to do anything server side. Use React's `componentDidMount` callback to handle client side code & rendering.